# Рисование массива изображений на Canvas

Tags: javascript

Работаю с JavaScript мало)

Нужно прорисовать массив изображений на canvas. 
С одним изображением все легко , вешаем прорисовку на image.onload , а как быть с массивом разных изображений?   
Делал так

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.src="img/img.bmp";
    array[i] = img;
}
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        array[i].onload = function(){
        context2D.drawImage(array[i], i*50, i*50);
};
```

``}

но ничего не рисуется и выкидывает "Uncaught TypeError: Type error (13:48:58:067 | error, javascript) at array.(anonymous function).onload " (работаю в NetBeans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `onload` срабатывает **после** отработки цикла, когда `i = 5` (а `array[i]`, соответственно, равен `undefined`; не забываем, что индексация идёт от нуля до `n - 1`, следовательно, `array[n]` уже не определён). Для защиты от подобного я предлягяю передавать `i` в `onload` следующим образом:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    array[i].onload = function(n){
        context2D.drawImage(array[n], n*50, n*50);
    }(i);
}
```

В такой реализации в функцию `onload` будет передано значение `i`, которое было на момент создания функции, а не в тот момент, когда функция была вызвана.

[Рабочий код](http://jsfiddle.net/8JynV/2/)

Comment: Во всех браузерах рабочий код (тот что по ссылке) работает на JSFIDDL-е, 
но если я делаю локально фаилы с таким де кодом то картинка отображается только в Опере( 
Если страницу несколько раз обновить то картинки появятся и в хроме и в мозилле.
Самое интересное прорисовка изображений вроде  как идет, я поставил 

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            array[i].onready = function(n) {
                context2D.drawImage(array[n], n * 5, n * 5);
                console.log(n+' done !');
            }(i);
        }
И в консоле " 0 done! ....... 4 done!" , но на canvas-е этого нет(

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что отрисовку вы делаете по `onready`. `onready` срабатывает по окончании загрузки DOM-контента __до__ загрузки изображений, стилей и прочего. Попробуйте `onload`.

Comment: Изменил но все равно) Пытался код вставить в комментарии но не получилось - ужасное форматирование после отправки.
 
Все это у меня работает при нажатии на кнопку, при первом нажатии заполняется массив и вешается .drawImage на onload каждой картинки, при повторном нажатии идет обыкновенная прорисовка. 
Так вот при первом нажатии картинки не рисуются - только при повторном нажатии( 
Добавил таймер с функцией прорисовки, и вставил его в код "первого" нажатия - рисует. Но это костыль

Comment: Путем экспериментов было выявлено что прорисовка происходит при >6мс в таймере

Answer (score 1):

До отрисовки крайне желательно загрузить все изображения. В самом простом проявлении, выглядит это, примерно, так:

```
function loadImages(pathes, cb) {
 var images = [];
 var imagesToLoad = pathes.length;
 function onImageLoadded() {
  if(!--imagesToLoad) {
    cb(images);
  }
 }

 for(var i=0; i<pathes.length; ++i) {
  var img = new Image();
  images.push(img);
  img.src = pathes[i];
  img.onload = onImageLoadded;
 }
}
```

соответственно:

```
function drawImages(array) {
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
  context2D.drawImage(array[i], i*50, i*50);
 }
}

loadImages([
  'some image path',
  'some image path 2',
  'some image path N'
 ],
 drawImages
);
```

Если в вашем проекте будет много асинхронного кода, то рекомендую использовать [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async/) или похожие решения, так-же можете использовать Promises библиотечки - [Promises/A+ спецификация](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/), [список некоторых реализаций](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md) (warning: не все из них production ready, но определить это не сложно)

ps: Код не тестировался и писался на скорую руку, могут быть ошибки.